# Multithreading in Tcl script

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I've started playing around with thread in Tcl and encountered a basic problem. I've started with a simple example from a textbox which doesn't seem to work.

```
package require Thread
for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 3} {incr thread} {
    set id [::thread::create {
        for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
            after [expr {int(500*rand()) }]
            puts "Thread [::thread::id] says hello"
        }
    }]
    puts "Started thread $id"
}

puts "Exiting threads [::thread::names]"
while {[llength [::thread::names]] > 1} {after 500}
puts "The end"
```

The `puts` inside the inner loop isn't executed.
What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me when I test it. Some sort of local misconfiguration? Any error messages anywhere?

Comment: No error messages. I'm using ActiveTcl 8.5. The output is: `Started thread tid0000149C
Started thread tid00000E34
Started thread tid00002F24
Exiting threads tid00002F24 tid00000E34 tid0000149C tid00000C78
The end`

Comment: The good old "you need `stdout` in the other thread"...

Comment: From your output I infer that you run this script on windows. Do you run in in `tclsh` or in `wish`? Wish on windows does some crazy stuff like closing `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` and replace it with channels that output to the console. See http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview?name=e8efa378a9

Comment: I run it in `wish`

Comment: I tried the same code in `tclsh` and indeed it's OK. Can you please help to fix the code above?

Comment: It's not that easy. The probably easiest way would be to create a reflected channel that passes the call to an other channel on an other thread (which needs the eventloop running).

Comment: Thank you Johannes. For small operations I think I'll utilize the `after $SomeValue {do something}`. For bigger, I might use another instance of the entire application